# Error occurred in deployment step Uninstall app for SharePoint.The local SharePoint server is not available

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012

Check that server is running and connected to SharePoint farm.

After giving database owner rights and farm administrator rights to the user. Yet it is not working. And giving the same Exception.

Comment: Can you check event log for more information of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the above error switch back to system account and open the SQL server management studio and assign the db_owner permissions to an account which you are using to deploy the app for below databases.

1. SharePoint_Config.
2. SharePoint_Admin_ [GUID].
3. Your current web application that needs to host the app.
4. Appmanagement_Service_DB (app management service application
   database).
5. SubscriptionSettings_Service_DB (Subscription Settings service
   application database).

Provide full control permissions to the site collection where we are deploying the app.

You have all the required the permissions now, to cross verify try to browse the site "http://sharepoint-journey.com/sites/appdevelopment" where you want to deploy the app, if you are able to open the site, then  you are ready to deploy the app.

- See more at: http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/app-development-in-sharepoint.html#sthash.2JzFiBkD.dpuf

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this make sure the logged in user is

1. DB Owner of Configuration Database
2. DB Owner of Content Database

You can refer this http://blog.aditi.com/enterprise_social/challenges-starting-developing-apps-sharepoint-2013/ for the challenges and workarounds while developing apps in SharePoint 2013

Comment: Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': We're sorry, we weren't able to complete the operation, please try again in a few minutes. If you see this message repeatedly, contact your administrator.

Comment: It is giving me now above given error

Comment: Try giving DBO permission on database AppMng_Service_DB

Comment: It is already given ...

Comment: What should be the URL in properties of Visual sutdio??

Comment: It should be the site where you want to deploy the app.

Comment: Yeah Amal I have given the url then of the site..

Comment: Okay fine amal I got the answer thanks for your contribution & help..